# Cordova: storing permanent data on Android and iOS

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to store data permanently on Cordova for both Android and iOS. By permanently, I mean if even user uninstall the mobile app it remain there so if they install it again I would be able to reuse it.

I am relying on this plugin `https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage` which uses `keychain` on iOS and `SharedPreferences` on Android.

The iOS works as expected, I can delete and install app and see that my data is still there.

In Android data get's cleared as soon as I uninstall. (the android device is secured which means it has a lock screen and I can confirm that it writes to SharedPreferences by looking into it with `stetho`)

I was thinking that it gets removed because the allowbackup default might be false, but even when I turned it into True, it's still not working.

```xml
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:allowBackup="true" />
        </edit-config>
</platform>
```

I will appreciate your help in advance...

(I added Android tag because there might be some android devs that know the reason of SharedPreference data getting deleted...)

Answer (score 2):

For small amounts of key/value data (e.g. app settings) you can use [cordova-plugin-cloud-settings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-cloud-settings).

Install it into your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cloud-settings --variable ANDROID_BACKUP_SERVICE_KEY="<API_KEY>"
```

Save some data and it will be backed up in the platform's cloud storage.

```
cordova.plugin.cloudsettings.save({
  user: {
    id: 1678,
    name: 'Fred',
    preferences: {
      mute: true,
      locale: 'en_GB'
    }
  }
});
```

You can then load the data even after the app has been re-installed:

```
cordova.plugin.cloudsettings.load(function(settings){
    console.log("Successfully loaded settings");
    console.dir(settings);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you uninstalled app, the data of SharedPreference also deleted,because it's in a position belong this app, to ensure other app can get your data when you set mode is private. if you want some data, storing state ignore is your app uninstalled, you should write a file on sdcard or external storage directory. but it will only available until android-Q.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the plugin [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

and the problem was solved.

In the config.xml to aggregate

```
<platform name="android">
...
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="true" />
...
</platform>
```

view more detail of plugin in a example in [cordova-custom-config-example](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml)

and documentation of andoid in [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)